# Using the Pumping Lemma to Prove $L = \{a^ib^jc^k \mid k = i*j\}$ is not Context-Free

Tags: proof-writing, formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

I want to use the Pumping Lemma to prove that

$$L = \{a^ib^jc^k \mid k = i*j\}$$

is not context-free. I think I have the intuition, but I don't know how to prove it. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part of on how to the proof $L$ is not context-free.**

> Assume L is context-free and prove it's not

To prove that $L$ is not context-free we use the Pumping Lemma for context-free languages. We assume that $L$ is a context-free language and by obtaining a contradiction to prove that $L$ is not a context-free language.

> define the pumping length, this is something that should exists if $L$ is context free, we don't really care what that value could be. We only care whether it exist or not.

Let $p$ be the pumping length for $L$ that is guaranteed to exists by the pumping lemma, such that $p \geq 1$

> Define a string that $\in L$ that we can "pump". We want some string of at length $> p$ so that we can divide it in the given format, then pump it and show we always end up with contradicting one of the conditions of the pumping lemma. We will take the subset of string in $L$ where $i$, $j$ are equal such that we have as many $a's and b's $ as that we have $c's$

Let $s = a^p b^p c^{p^2} \in L$

Because $s \in L$ and the length of $s$ will always be greater than $p$ we may divide $s$ into five pieces $s = uvxyz$ that satisfy the following conditions:

1. for each $i \geq 0$, $uv^ixy^iz \in L$
2. $|vy| > 0$, ( $v$ and $y$ cannot both be the empty string) and
3. $|vxy| \leq p$ (the length of $vxy$ can be at most $p$)

**Show that all possible cases you can divide your $s$ into the five pieces as stated by the lemma, yet for each case you end up pumping by a certain value for $i$ such that you end up with a string that $\notin L$**

**Description of cases**

Take $p=4$ then our string looks like $aaaa\ bbbb\ cccc\ cccc\ cccc \in L$ *Note the spaces are for readability only*
We divide our string in two ways such that we satisfy both condition 2 and 3 of

**Case 1** $vxy$ contains one symbol:

$v$ and $y$ contain both: only a's, only b's or only c's
so you have $vxy = "aaaa" \lor "bbbb" \lor "cccc"$

**Case 2** : $v$ contains a's and b's and $y$ contains b's

we take $vxy = "ab\ b\ b"$

**Case 3** : $v$ contains b's and c's and $y$ contains c's

we take  $vxy = "bb\ b\ c"$

> These are the cases I find. Because of the pumping length we have that our $vxy$ can never have all three symbols, since there are exactly the same amount of b's a any chosen P.
>
> Then for each take $i \geq 0$, $uv^ixy^iz \notin L$ to show we always have a $i$ that contradicts with condition 1 of the lemma since our string $\notin L$ anymore.
>
> > For case 1 take some number like $i = 10$
>
> You have a string with more a's such that the string $\notin L$ anymore.
>
> > case 2: take some number like $i = 10$
>
> You have a string with more a's and b's such that the string $\notin L$ anymore.
>
> > case 3: take some number like $i = 10$
>
> You have a string with more b's and c's such that the string $\notin L$ anymore.

Because one of these cases must always happen you will always have a contradiction as result, thus an contradiction is unavoidable. So the assumption that $L$ is a context-free language must be false. Thus we have proved $L$ is not a context-free language.

Comment: Thanks! That s was what I was looking for!

Comment: are you sure there would be only 3 possible cases?

Comment: I will elaborate on my answer a bit more. 3 cases might not be precise enough for the language you defined.

Comment: Updated answer. Correct me if you think I might be missing something.

Comment: I'd like to ask a bit more. For example case $w = a^n$, $vxy = b^n$ and $z = c^n^2$ with i = 100 is proof like #a(s) * #b(s) != #c(s)? # means count of char in word s.

Comment: I think that depends on how precisely you formulate this proof. If you state that for i = 100 you have must have the you must have $i$ amount of a's followed by $i$ amount of b's followed by $i * i$ amount of c's. Yet have pumped by $i$ and end up with string with that doesn't satisfy the predicate from you language, thus not in L. And since the string is not in L you derive a contradiction. Most important fact is that in the end you conclude that pumping the string resulted in a string not in L. Only then you may conclude the contradiction.

Comment: Also notice that all other cases of $uvw$ can by no means be pumped. Only pumping one case with some big $i$ doesn't proof what you try to establish.Which is that there can be no string formed with $s = uvxyz$ to satisfy the 3 conditions. Thus you conclude that there exists no pumping length $p$. Hence you obtained a contradiction and can conclude L can't be a context-free language. Thus your prove is now complete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100139/discussion-between-lasto-and-joshuarms).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. Use [Parikh's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh%27s_theorem) on the commutative image of context-free languages.